# Category theory to the rescue of hard-working mathematicians

Tags: category-theory

I would like to know some examples of general mathematical results or theorems, which are difficult to prove without the methods of category theory, but which formulated in the language of category theory are easy.

One famous example is Brouwer's fixed point theorem, which using the category of punctuated topological spaces $\text{Top}_*$ and the category of groups $\text{Grp}$ is very easy to prove (to each topological $S\in \text{Top}_*$ space, let's consider the functor which assigns it is fundamental group $\pi_1(S)\in\text{Grp}$).

But, I would like to know other, less-known, examples.

Comment: You can prove the fixed point theorem without category theory.

Comment: I wouldn't say that fundamental group roof of the Brouwer fixed point theorem is "simpler," given all the things you have to prove about the fundamental group functor $\pi$ before you can prove Brouwer. $\pi$ does not magically appear in category theory - you still need to get down and dirty.

Comment: @JohnDouma The question doesn't say it is necessary, just cleaner, or maybe clarifying. But, while it is, in some ways, clarifying, I'm not sure it is cleaner.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't think it makes it cleaner or any clearer either. The insight that a homeomorphism preserves an algebraic structure doesn't require a further abstraction.

Comment: Studying homology theory in abelian categories definitely lets you avoid a lot of repeated work. Not sure that counts as the kind of thing you are asking.

Comment: I think you are missing the main point of category theory as used in algebraic topology and other "clients" of category theory: the role of category is to provide a framework for understanding concepts like "fundamental group" (as a functor from the category of topological spaces to the category of groups). This framework helps to abbreviate lots of standard assumptions about these concepts, but it doesn't usually give you much help with finding proofs with a significant geometric content - your "famous example" of a proof makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: The fundamental group only proves Brouwer's theorem for the $2$-dimensional ball. What this proof suggests is to search for other functors which can be used for the higher dimansional cases.